# Unable to create Dart Project in Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I have installed Android studio v4.0.1 on my MAC.

When i try to create a new project in android studio via **File->New->NewProject->BasicActivity** I couldn't find dart in language option for new project. Basically, I am trying to create a new dart project.

[image]

Below is the doctor output: Under Android studio, flutter and dart seems to be ticked and ok.

mboobesh$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G6020, locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 1.17.5 at /Users/mboobesh/Documents/Dev/flutter
• Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (5 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
• Engine revision ee76268252
• Dart version 2.8.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/mboobesh/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
Or install Xcode via the App Store.
Once installed, run:
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
✗ CocoaPods not installed.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install:
sudo gem install cocoapods

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• **Flutter plugin version 47.1.2**
• **Dart plugin version 193.7361**
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2)
• IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
✗ **Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.**
✗ **Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.**
• For information about installing plugins, see
https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
:~

Moreover, if i go to android studio preferences, there i could see Dart and its SDK path. Plugins are showing that Flutter and Dart are installed and up to date.

[image]

Additionally, I have installed intelliJ separately in my Mac, where i could see Dart in new project selection. Am i missing something to install in Android studio? that is why it is not showing Dart language in new project settings? please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create Flutter project as I understand.There is no Dart project. There is Flutter project which uses dart language. You need to install flutter plug-in on android studio. and there will be create new flutter project option.

This is from where you are creating flutter project:
[image]

If this option is not there that means you have not installed flutter plugin on android studio.
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor Check this out if there is not this option.

Comment: Hi, I am new to flutter. yes i am trying to create a flutter project which uses dart language. While prompting to create a new project, it shows only Kotlin and Java. Snapshot given above. Why is it not listing "Dart"? Also, doctor output shows Flutter and Dart plugins are already installed. doctor output shows flutter and dart plugins are already installed. [✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 48.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment.

Comment: It does not list dart because it should not. In the picture you are already at native project creation, so there is no flutter and dart there. I updated my answer check out.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. One more clarification. I installed IntelliJ. It shows dart and i could execute a hello world program as well. But flutter doctor -v shows cross mark. flutter and dart plugins are installed. any idea? [!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

Answer (score 1):

just add Flutter to your androidStudio plugin go to :
Start Android Studio.
Open plugin preferences " preference->plugin " (Configure > Plugins as of v3.6.3.0 or later).
Select the Flutter plugin and click Install.
Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin.
Click Restart when prompted.

that's all !

Comment: Hi, This was already done. flutter and dart plugins are already installed and up to date. Is there any other option to try?

Comment: [✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 48.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)